# NodeJS: protoc generated files not generating service definition

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-js

Have a relatively simple `helloworld.proto` file down below

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

service Greeter { rpc SayHello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse); }

message HelloRequest { string name = 1; }

message HelloResponse { string message = 1; }
```

When I run `protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. .\helloworld.proto` it generates a `helloworld_pb.js` file but it doesn't include my `Greeter` service nor my `SayHello` rpc function. Looked around a few other post and also Google's reference (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/overview) and it seems like I need to include a `--plugin` option but I can't seem to find any. Does anybody have a solution to for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `protoc` plugin for Node gRPC is distributed in the [`grpc-tools` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-tools). That package provides a tool `grpc_tools_node_protoc` that is a version of `protoc` that automatically includes the plugin.

As described in that package's README, when you run the tool you will also need to use the `--grpc_out` argument to control the plugin. The question is tagged `grpc-js`, so you will probably want to use the `grpc_js` option for that argument to generate code that interacts with `grpc-js`.

Comment: Yes thank you for you help. I got the answer a few days back but I forgot to update here. Installing the grpc-tools globally and using the following command did what I needed. Thank you! `grpc_tools_node_protoc.cmd --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. --grpc_out=generate_package_definition:. .\contacts.proto`

Answer (score 1):

For those that have been looking for an example that also generates typescript see below

```
grpc_tools_node_protoc.cmd --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:.\output --grpc_out=generate_package_definition:.\output *.proto

grpc_tools_node_protoc.cmd  --plugin=protoc-gen-ts.cmd=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --ts_out=.\typescript -I .\output *.proto
```